# After creating the sandbox, I tried to login but it requires verification code?

Tags: sandbox

After I have created a new sandbox from a sandbox model, I clicked the login link in the sandbox page and tried login with my credential. But it asked me to type in the credential which is sent to ****@***.invalid ?

I feel like what is that logic? Anyone facing the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you did not create the original sandbox, and you logged in to that sandbox at some point, and you never updated your email address in that sandbox, this is definitely something that could happen. Make sure you log in to the original sandbox, update your email address, then refresh the new sandbox you created. Alternatively, you can have another administrator log in to that sandbox and fix your email address and/or password.